# Spring MVC ajax POST request fails when sending large string

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am working on web-app which includes some sort of web based XML editor. Basically I use html textarea as my "editor" and when user clicks "save" button, AJAX post request containing modified XML is sent to server. I use $.ajax function

```
 function saveXML(){
     var cm = editor.mirror; 
     var textXML = cm.getValue(); // textXML is a String representing edited XML
     $.ajax({
            url: "saveEditedBatch",
            data: {xmlString: textXML}, 
            type: 'POST',
            success : function(response){

            },
            error : function (){  
                alert("error");
            } 
        });
```

on server side I have controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEditedBatch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse saveEditedBatch(@RequestParam(value = "xmlString") String xmlString){
    JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
    byte[] byteXML = xmlString.getBytes();
    byteXML =  xmlAccess(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteXML));

    // do something with byteXML

    return response;
}
```

When my XML and hence the String that I send to server is small - everything works fine. However when XML is large - I get "HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'xmlString' is not present" even though I know I am passing it. What can I do?

Comment: What application server do you use?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. I changed server.xml file of my apache tomcat. Namelly, I  set maxPostSize to -1 meaning unlimited. Thanks, to ragnor - pointed the direction )))

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your string size and you have mentioned that error code is 400.
For long strings , error code is 414 - uri too large and it comes for a GET request having a limit of nearly 8000 characters.

Comment: well... when I pass short strings - it works ) when I try to pass large one it fails. What is the problem then?

Comment: Hi error code 400 comes hwen your request is malformed. As per W3,org "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications. " This means your request when long is getting malformed, please have look at the request.